# Union two columns in the same table and save the result into other column within same table in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I am a beginner here so that, I need your help in order to fix my program for my last project.
I'd like to union of two columns which are `frequent1x` and `frequent2x` and store the result into column `frequent2`.

I use this query..

```
Insert into tvfrequent (no, frequent1, frequent1x, frequent2x, frequent2, frequent3, frequent4, frequent5, support)
SELECT no,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' ', 1 ) AS frequent1,                   
(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' ', 2 ),' ',-1) AS frequent1x) union (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' -1 ', 2 ),' -1 ',-1) AS frequent2x) As frequent2,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' -1 ', 3 ),' -1 ',-1) AS frequent3,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' -1 ', 4 ),' -1 ',-1) AS frequent4,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' -1 ', 5 ),' -1 ',-1) AS frequent5,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' -1 ', -1 ) AS support
FROM tspade
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _"it didn't work"_ -- what do you mean? Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following query:

```
Insert into tvfrequent (no, frequent1, frequent1x, frequent2x, frequent2, frequent3, frequent4, frequent5, support)
SELECT no,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' ', 1 ) AS frequent1,                   
concat
      (
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' ', 2 ),' ',-1)
       ,
       " "
       ,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' -1 ', 2 ),' -1 ',-1)      
      ) As frequent2,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' -1 ', 3 ),' -1 ',-1) AS frequent3,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' -1 ', 4 ),' -1 ',-1) AS frequent4,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' -1 ', 5 ),' -1 ',-1) AS frequent5,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' -1 ', -1 ) AS support
FROM tspade;
```

Alternative approach:

```
Insert into tvfrequent (no, frequent1, frequent1x, frequent2x, frequent2, frequent3, frequent4, frequent5, support)
    SELECT no,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' ', 1 ) AS frequent1,                   
    (case
        when
           (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' ', 2 ),' ',-1))
       =          
           (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' -1 ', 2 ),' -1 ',-1))
        then
           (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' ', 2 ),' ',-1))
        else
            (concat
                   (
                     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' ', 2 ),' ',-1)
                       ,
                      " "
                       ,
                     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' -1 ', 2 ),' -1 ',-1)      
                   )
           )           
    ) As frequent2,    
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' -1 ', 3 ),' -1 ',-1) AS frequent3,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' -1 ', 4 ),' -1 ',-1) AS frequent4,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' -1 ', 5 ),' -1 ',-1) AS frequent5,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetime , ' -1 ', -1 ) AS support
    FROM tspade;
```

Comment: i tried this but i like to avoid redundancy from some duplicate data.. that's why i prefer union,, anyway thx for this

Comment: Please try the alternative approach. It may work but i didn't tested it. Kindly comment whether its workin or not.

Comment: I tried that one then the result is :

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union
      (select   
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( unixdatetim' at line 9

Comment: I have edited the alternative approach. It'll check for the duplication and if both strings are different then merge it. Please try it out.

Comment: i tried the updated one and it worked and helpful. thank you Harshil